# jQuery DataTables - No XHR request made

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I have a simple datatable with the following initialization options:

```
$('#inventory').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "ajax": '/api/inventory/',
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "description" },
        { "data": "cost_price" },
        { "data": "sale_price" },
        { "data": "on_hand" }
    ]
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="inventory">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1">ID</th>
            <th tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Description</th>
            <th tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Cost Price</th>
            <th tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Sale Price</th>
            <th tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1">On Hand</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">ID</th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Description</th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Cost Price</th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Sale Price</th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Stock</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my [debug bookmarklet](http://debug.datatables.net/icunex). I noticed that under server interaction it says `Last JSON from server: No XHR request made`. In the frontend i see `No data available in table` where my data should be. There's no error in the Chrome console and if I hit the URL with my browser it returns the JSON fine. What can cause DataTables to not make the XHR request?

Comment: make sure you are using correct API docs based on version. last release changed the API a lot. try changing `ajax` to `sAjaxSource`

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl it was definitely a versions thing. Got it sorted out by upgrading to version 1.10. `sAjaxSource` did work with my version btw. Is there a way to see old docs?

Comment: look for `legacy site`